# facebook api post return value

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

im posting something to my wall using the php facebook api.
like this:

```
$postid = $facebook->api('/JonasDevelopment/feed', 'post', array('message'=>  $postcontent , 'access_token' => "myaccesstoken", 'cb' => ''));
```

The result i get back in $postid  looks like json:

```
a:1:{s:2:"id";s:31:"491965997521672_714151951969741";}
```

however when i do to get the post id :

```
$valuearray = json_decode($postid, true);
echo $valuearray['id'];
```

nothing shows up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FB seems to be quite inconsistent in their return format of post id. First part here is the user id – so strip it of, so that you have `714151951969741` – with that ID you should be able to access the post via Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$postid` seems wrong to me. Anyways, I think the you are accessing the value of `id` in a wrong way, rather try this-

```
echo $valuearray->{'id'};
```

You can also debug by dumping the value of `$valuearray`- `var_dump($valuearray)`

Comment: Not wrong, because of second parameter of `json_decode`.

Comment: @CBroe, yes, I got it

Answer (score 0):

actually i didn't need to decode json, it works like this:

```
 var_dump(strstr($postid['id'], '_', true));
```

thanks anyway for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these  code

```
 $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                             ));
    echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
```

It will return you the posted id